# What's the difference between composite primary index and two primary indexes?

Tags: mysql

I'm using phpmyadmin and have discovered that you can only have one `PRIMARY` key/index (if they're interchangeable in that context) for a table, but it can contain multiple columns.

If you can have such, why does it not allow the creation of more than one `PRIMARY` key/index?

Comment: That's because a composite index with 2 columns is different to 2 separate indexes. Imagine a phone book that was sorted only by first name. And another book that is only sorted by last name. Now given those 2 books find a person named "John Doe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can only have one PRIMARY key/index [...] for a table, but it can contain multiple columns.

This is correct.

> If you can have such, why does it not allow the creation of more than one PRIMARY key/index?

The role of a primary key is to act as a *unique* identifier for a given row within a table. If you perform a search trying to match a PK, you get 1 result if there's a match, or 0 if no such PK exists in it.

OTOH, columns simply represent attributes that describe the object stored in a single row. If you have a `Person` table, then you could have something like:

```
------
Person
------
id: int, pk, autoincrement
name: varchar
dob: datetime
```

where `id`, `name`, and `dob` are columns describing any given `Person` stored in a row, with `id` uniquely identifying every one of them.

> But how does this explain the difference between having a composite primary key and having two separate primary keys?

You can only have a single PK per table. However, you can combine several columns to create a composite PK in cases where it's useful. Often, when several columns are combined, these columns are found in associative tables and are mapped foreign keys (FKs) mapped to primary keys (PKs) in other independent tables.

Composite keys tend to be used in associative tables, which are used to express `M:M` relations.

Combining PKs from several other tables in a single associative table allows you to uniquely identify a specific match.

For example, consider a grocery store. There's a `M:M` relation between people and stores, b/c every store can have many people buying in it, and people can visit any store they like.

Suppose you have a central database for all your stores and you want to track orders. We could have something like this:

```
+--------+
| Person |
+--------+
id: int, pk, autoincrement
name: varchar

+-------+
| Store |
+-------+
id: int, pk, autoincrement
name: varchar
address: varchar

+-------+
| Order |
+-------+
person_id: int, fk to Person.id
store_id: int, fk to Store.id
date_placed: datetime
...
```

In the `Order` table, the `person_id`, `store_id` and `date_placed` columns can be combined into a single *composite* PK so that we can *uniquely* identify every individual order.

The fact that they're treated as a PK implies that you cannot have more than one matching row for any given combination, so it helps with referential integrity constraints: if anything tries to insert a new row using repeated information, the database will reject that attempt due to a PK constraint violation, which guarantees that PKs are unique.

There're other benefits, but this is one way in which composite PKs can be very useful.

Comment: Ahh, so it's more about having unique combinations, since if we have separate PKs for each column, they're not really considered a group or a combination, and therefore cannot be used to uniquely identify a record as a group, yeah? That clears it up. Thanks so much!

Comment: @herondale You always have a single PK per *table*, not column. However, to create a PK, you must use *at least* one column. If you combine multiple columns in some table `A` to create a single PK, then you've created a composite PK. Those columns could themselves be simple columns that exist only in `A` or could actually be FKs, which means that they're PKs mapped from some other table `B` or `C`, and so on.  In either case, each table `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. will still have a single PK each, regardless of how many separate columns were combined in each individual table.

Answer (score 0):

A primary key has three properties:

- The keys are not null.
- The keys are unique (in combination).
- There is only one of them on a table.

In addition, MySQL uses the primary key for clustering the table -- the rows are actually stored in sorted order.  Not all databases do this.

The last condition -- clustering -- pretty much explains why you can have only one primary key in a table.  However, the first two conditions can be implemented using `unique` and `not null` constraints for other columns.

The primary key can be composite, that is, composed of multiple keys.  You would declare this as:

```
create table t (
    a . . .,
    b . . .,
    primary key (a, b)
);
```

Comment: But how does this explain the difference between having a composite primary key and having two separate primary keys? I'm sorry, it's still a little vague to me

Comment: @herondale In a table you cannot have two separate primary keys. It's possible you can have two candidate keys, each can be used as a primary key. But you can only set one. Where as a composite key of two column means it takes values from these two column to uniquely identify each row. One column along won't do the job.